# How to obtain a confidence interval for the cumulative incidence (1-KM) via "log" formula?

Tags: confidence-interval, survival, kaplan-meier

I want to show the "mirror" to the survival probability calculated with the Kaplan-Meier estimator, that is the cumulative incidence (or probability).

I would like to add the pointwise confidence interval. In my software it is provided for the Kaplan-Meier, but not for the CIF=1-KM.

I guess it's as easy as just swapping the ends and subtract from 1, that is [0.2 ; 0.6] --> [1-0.6 ; 1-0.2] --> [0.4, 0.8]

That's the Greenwood plain one. But I want also the one on the log-scale. It is asymmetric. But can I just swap the KM CI for the survival and get the CI for my cumulative incidence?

By the way, is there any proper name for the "log" CI? I mean - "a variance estimator calculated using the cumulative hazard" or maybe "Greenwood estimator on the log-scale"?

---

Just to make 100% clear - I have NO competing risks. This is not competing risk adjusted CIF. This is just pure 1-KM cumulative probability with just one kind of event and censoring.

Answer (score 1):

The cumulative incidence function with just one event possible for each individual is, as you note, $F(t)=1-S(t)$, where $S(t)$ is the survival function over time. That's by definition.

Whether $S(t)$ is estimated by Kaplan-Meier or other methods doesn't matter. For confidence limits, you can just replace $S(t)$ in that formula with its upper confidence limit and lower confidence limit, as you suggest. Again, it doesn't matter how the confidence limits were determined or whether they are symmetric.

[Klein and Moeschberger](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387953991) use the simple phrase "log-transformed confidence interval" on page 105, so that should do.

Comment: +1, but for future readers note that, in general, it is not sufficient to evaluate the transformed variable at the endpoints of a CI (though it works here). For instance, if $(-1, 2)$ is a CI for $\theta$ and $\phi = \theta^2$ it would be a mistake to assume that $(1, 4)$ is the corresponding CI for $\phi$. Instead, consider all values inside the CI to obtain $(0, 4)$.